# Java swing: managing integers/doubles with Listeners and J*Fields

Tags: java, swing

***EDITED***

I've probably just stared at the screen for WAYYY too long but I feel the need to submit this question prior to going to sleep incase my delirium remains true...

The problem I'm having is I'm trying to get an int/double from the JTextField textField and convert it to a(n) int/double to use later in a listener, after retrieving it from a listener... ListenForText implements KeyListener, specifically KeyTyped, to obtain, through toString(), and store it in a String txtFldAmnt. After which I will store the result of Integer.parseInt(txtFldAmnt) into fldAmnt (fldAmnt = Integer.pareseInt(txtFldAmnt)) LINE 99 if copied to an editor. Once it's converted into an int I want to be able to manipulate it and then use it again, at LINE 173, to display, in a new window, the fldAmnt. Honestly, I don't really care about whether it's an int or String displayed, but I know a String is required for JTextField. What magic am I missing? Answers are always welcome but I prefer a chance to learn. Also, as I'm fairly new to Java, off topic pointers, criticism, and better ways to implement this code is greatly welcomed :)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class GUI extends JFrame{

/**
 * wtf is the serial version UID = 1L
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JButton wdBtn;
private JButton dpBtn;
private JButton xferBtn;
private JButton balBtn;
private JRadioButton chkRadio;
private JRadioButton savRadio;
private JTextField textField;
private static String txtFldAmnt;
private static int fldAmnt = 0;
private static Double chkBal = 0.00;
private static Double savBal = 0.00;


public static void main(String[] args){
    new GUI();
}


public GUI() {

    //default location and size
    this.setSize(300,182);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("ATM Machine");

    //add buttons
    wdBtn = new JButton("Withdraw");
    dpBtn = new JButton("Deposit");
    xferBtn = new JButton("Transfer");
    balBtn = new JButton("Show Balance");
    chkRadio = new JRadioButton("Checking");
    chkRadio.setSelected(false);
    savRadio = new JRadioButton("Savings");
    savRadio.setSelected(false);
    textField = new JTextField("", 20);
    final JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Enter amount: ");
    textField.setToolTipText("Enter amount");

    //Listener class to pass button listeners
    ListenForButton lForButton = new ListenForButton();
    wdBtn.addActionListener(lForButton);
    dpBtn.addActionListener(lForButton);
    xferBtn.addActionListener(lForButton);
    balBtn.addActionListener(lForButton);
    chkRadio.addActionListener(lForButton);
    savRadio.addActionListener(lForButton);

    ListenForText textFieldListener = new ListenForText();
    textField.addKeyListener(textFieldListener);

    //Configure layouts
    JPanel PANEL = new JPanel();
    PANEL.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2, 5, 10));
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,10,10));
    panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

    //add buttons to their panels
    panel1.add(wdBtn);
    panel1.add(dpBtn);
    panel1.add(xferBtn);
    panel1.add(balBtn);
    panel2.add(chkRadio);
    panel2.add(savRadio);
    panel3.add(textLabel);
    panel3.add(textField);

    PANEL.add(panel1);
    PANEL.add(panel2);
    PANEL.add(panel3);

    this.add(PANEL);
    //this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
//implement listeners
private class ListenForText implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        txtFldAmnt = (e.toString());
        fldAmnt = Integer.parseInt(txtFldAmnt);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        //maybe do case/switch statements
        if (e.getSource() == wdBtn) {
            JFrame newFrame = new JFrame("Withdraw Title");
            newFrame.setResizable(false);
            newFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            newFrame.setSize(300, 91);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JLabel newLbl = new JLabel("Withdraw Frame", JLabel.CENTER);

            panel.add(newLbl);
            newFrame.add(panel);
            newFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == dpBtn) {
            JFrame newFrame = new JFrame("Deposit Title");
            /*
             * Set the newFrame.setSize(300,182); to this comment in the if statement to place
             * the window directly over current window
             */
            newFrame.setResizable(false);
            newFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            newFrame.setSize(300, 91);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JLabel newLbl = new JLabel("Deposit Frame", JLabel.CENTER);

            panel.add(newLbl);
            newFrame.add(panel);
            newFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == xferBtn) {
            JFrame newFrame = new JFrame("Transfer Title");

            newFrame.setResizable(false);
            newFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            newFrame.setSize(300, 91);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JLabel newLbl = new JLabel("Transfer Frame", JLabel.CENTER);

            panel.add(newLbl);
            newFrame.add(panel);
            newFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == balBtn){
            JFrame newFrame = new JFrame("Balance Title");

            newFrame.setResizable(false);
            newFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            newFrame.setSize(300, 91);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JTextField newLbl = new JTextField(Integer.toString(fldAmnt));

            panel.add(newLbl);
            newFrame.add(panel);
            newFrame.setVisible(true);

        }
    }
}
}
```

-cheers

***EDITED BELOW***

Thank for the answers, and I'm sorry for the horrible description... but I found a work around, thoguh I'm not sure if it's appropriate. 
with the above example:

```
fldAmnt = Integer.pareseInt(txtFldAmnt)
```

i just added a .getText() //Though I rewrote the entire source code

```
fldAmnt = Integer.pareseInt(txtFldAmnt.getText())
```

it's worked for me for my entire program.

I wish I didn't have to post my entire code below but I haven't decided on a great place to store all of my code yet.
***(SUGGESTIONS ARE WELCOME :D)***

but here it is:
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.border.*;

```
public class ATM extends JFrame{
//buttons needed
JButton wBtn;
JButton dBtn;
JButton xBtn;
JButton bBtn;
//radios needed
JRadioButton cRadio;
JRadioButton sRadio;
//Text field needed
JTextField txt;
JLabel txtLabel;
static int withdraw = 0;
Double amount = 0.00;
Double cBal = 100.00;
Double sBal = 100.00;


double number1, number2, totalCalc;

public static void main(String[] args){

    new Lesson22();

}
public ATM(){
    this.setSize(400, 200);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("My Third Frame");

    wBtn = new JButton("Withdraw");

    dBtn = new JButton("Deposit");
    xBtn = new JButton("Transfer");
    bBtn = new JButton("Show Balance");
    cRadio = new JRadioButton("Checking");
    sRadio = new JRadioButton("Savings");
    txtLabel = new JLabel("Amount: $");
    txt = new JTextField("", 10);

    JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();

    // Create an instance of ListenForEvents to handle events

    ListenForButton lForButton = new ListenForButton();

    wBtn.addActionListener(lForButton);
    dBtn.addActionListener(lForButton);
    xBtn.addActionListener(lForButton);
    bBtn.addActionListener(lForButton);


    // How to add a label --------------------------

    // Creates a group that will contain radio buttons
    // You do this so that when 1 is selected the others
    // are deselected

    ButtonGroup operation = new ButtonGroup();

    // Add radio buttons to the group

    operation.add(cRadio);
    operation.add(sRadio);

    // Create a new panel to hold radio buttons

    JPanel operPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel btnPanel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel btnPanel2 = new JPanel();
    btnPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    btnPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    Border btnBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
    btnPanel1.setBorder(btnBorder);
    btnPanel1.add(wBtn);
    btnPanel1.add(dBtn);
    btnPanel2.setBorder(btnBorder);
    btnPanel2.add(xBtn);
    btnPanel2.add(bBtn);


    Border operBorder = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1);

    // Set the border for the panel

    operPanel.setBorder(operBorder);

    // Add the radio buttons to the panel

    operPanel.add(cRadio);
    operPanel.add(sRadio);


    // Selects the add radio button by default
    cRadio.setSelected(true);
    JPanel txtPanel = new JPanel();
    txtPanel.add(txtLabel);
    txtPanel.add(txt);


    thePanel.add(btnPanel1);
    thePanel.add(btnPanel2);
    thePanel.add(operPanel);
    thePanel.add(txtPanel);
    thePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
    this.add(thePanel);

    this.setVisible(true);

    txt.requestFocus();

}

private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener{

    // This method is called when an event occurs

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        /******************************************************
         * THIS IS FOR CHECKING
         *****************************************************/
        // Check if the source of the event was the button
        if(cRadio.isSelected()){
            if(e.getSource() == wBtn){
                try {
                    amount = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
                    cBal -= amount;
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException excep){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ATM.this, 
                            "Please enter a valid number in multiples of 20", 
                            "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            if(e.getSource() == bBtn){
                JFrame bFrame = new JFrame();
                bFrame.setSize(300, 182);
                bFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                JLabel cLabel = new JLabel(Double.toString(cBal));
                JLabel CLBL = new JLabel("Checking: ");
                panel.add(CLBL);
                panel.add(cLabel);
                bFrame.add(panel);
                bFrame.setVisible(true);
            }

            if(e.getSource() == dBtn){
                amount = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
                cBal += amount;
            }
            if(e.getSource() == xBtn){
                amount = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
                if (sBal >= 0 && sBal >= amount){
                    cBal += amount;
                    sBal -= amount;
                }
                else if (sBal < amount) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ATM.this,
                            "INSUFFICENT FUNDS", "ERROR", 
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }
        /******************************************************
         * THIS IS FOR SAVINGS
         *****************************************************/
        if(sRadio.isSelected()){
            if(e.getSource() == wBtn){
                try {
                    amount = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
                    if(sBal >= 0 && sBal >= amount){
                        sBal -= amount;
                    }
                    else if (sBal < amount) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ATM.this,
                                "INSUFFICENT FUNDS", "ERROR", 
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException excep){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ATM.this, 
                            "Please enter a valid number in multiples of 20", 
                            "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            if(e.getSource() == bBtn){
                JFrame bFrame = new JFrame();
                bFrame.setSize(300, 182);
                bFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                JLabel sLabel = new JLabel(Double.toString(sBal));
                JLabel SLBL = new JLabel("Savings: ");
                panel.add(SLBL);
                panel.add(sLabel);

                bFrame.add(panel);
                bFrame.setVisible(true);
            }

            if(e.getSource() == dBtn){
                try{
                    amount = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
                    sBal += amount;
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException excep){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ATM.this, 
                            "Please enter a valid number!", 
                            "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            if(e.getSource() == xBtn){
                amount = Double.parseDouble(txt.getText());
                if (cBal >= 0 && cBal >= amount){
                    sBal += amount;
                    cBal -= amount;
                }
                else if (cBal < amount) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ATM.this,
                            "INSUFFICENT FUNDS", "ERROR", 
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

...and by the way can anyone explain this warning message:
***The serializable class ATM does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long***

If not simply don't bother. I'll keep researching into it when I have time.

This is still not complete, but thank you all for your help!

Comment: `I've probably just stared at the screen for WAYYY too long` - so you need to learn to simplify the problem. Your question is about a JTextField. So create a simple JFrame with just a JTextField and forget all the other components. Once you solve the problem you the apply the solution to your real code. If you can't find the solution, then you have a simple demo to post (we don't want to look at hundreds of lines of code. This is called a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and should be posted with every question.

Comment: What problems are you having with your program? You don't explain the actual problem well at all, making it hard for us to understand. Also, you will **never** want to use KeyListeners on a JTextField. DocumentListener or DocumentFilter perhaps, but not a KeyListener.

Answer (score 3):

`KeyListener` on any `JTextComponent` is a bad idea.

To monitor changes to a text component, use a `DocumentListener`, to filter the content that a text component can handle, use a `DocumentFilter`.  See [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners), [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details.

In your case, it'd probably better to use a `JSpinner` or `JFormattedTextField` as they are designed to handle (amongst other things) numbers

See [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more details